# Other than tabbing all the way through it, what is the quickest way to fill out this web-based time input form?

Tags: google-classic-sites

In the form below, the tab index does what you think it does.  I have been entering this form the same way for years by tabbing through it, but I have a hunch there is a macro/script out there that can rep this out in a single click.

[click here for picture of data entry form](http://sites.google.com/site/micahbolen/Home) (link updated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not see the form either, but website form filling is the classical use case for **iMacros**. It is an open-source **web browser** macro recorder (as opposed to normal desktop macro recorders like AHK). I use it daily to [fill out lengthy web forms](http://wiki.imacros.net/Form_Filling) for [web regression testing](http://wiki.imacros.net/Web_Testing)). You can [download iMacros](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/firefox/) as free addon for IE, Firefox and Chrome.

iMacros filling out a very long, multi-page BPO web form:
[image: iMacros filling out a very long, multi-page BPO web form...]

Answer (score 0):

LastPass does form fills.
http://lastpass.com/help.php?topic=formfillbasic&nw=1&fromwebsite=1